# Best tool: Distributed load test for asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, .net, testing, load-testing

We want a high performance testing tool for a distributed scenario

We want to collect data from clients and from server (memory usage, cpu usage, response time, .net calls etc).

Most of our applications are using .Net 4.0 or Classic Asp.

We have 4 servers. We want 1 controller and three agents working together for testing, collecting data.

What's the best tool for this scenario?

ps: We've tried Visual studio 2012 ultimate and it seems promising. I don't know other tools that fits the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give Load Tester a try: http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/  (disclaimer: I work there). It has a monitoring agent that will run on your Windows servers to collect the metrics you mentioned and a lot more. It also collects client-side metrics such as page load time. The LITE version is free and can run simple tests with unlimited users.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Rational Performance Tester](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/tester/performance/workflow.html). I was about to purchase a license for one of our projects but didn't push through for reasons not related to the software. Looked promising back then.

Answer (score 0):

I would split things up to keep it simple.

First I would check what the average requests per seconds is when using your servers to generate load. For that there is a small tool included in Apache Http Server called `ab.exe`. It's easy to setup to generate requests.

If you think that you get acceptable response times all is well.

If not, use something like Jetbrains DotTrace (in your app) to collect data when generating load from one server.